# How to make each index-instance of Label components in the ListCellRenderer have the same width?

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I have a List , and in its ListCellRenderer class I put Labels to display "Labels" and data values.

The problem is that when there are more than one elements in the List then the Labels are not aligned , they do not have the same width. Although I used the following code but it does not do anything :

```
public CListCell(boolean displayPhoto, String[] libelles)
    {
        showPhoto = displayPhoto;
        if (displayPhoto)
        {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            addComponent(BorderLayout.WEST, pic);
        }
        else
            setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));

        labels = new Label[libelles.length];
        lData = new Label[libelles.length+1];

        for (int i=0;i<libelles.length+1;i++)
        {
            lData[i] = new Label("");
            lData[i].setAlignment(Label.LEFT);
            lData[i].getStyle().setMargin(Component.TOP, 1);
            lData[i].getStyle().setMargin(Component.BOTTOM, 1);
            lData[i].getStyle().setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
            if (i == libelles.length)
                break;
            labels[i] = new Label(libelles[i]);
            labels[i].setAlignment(Label.LEFT);
            labels[i].getStyle().setMargin(Component.TOP, 1);
            labels[i].getStyle().setMargin(Component.BOTTOM, 1);
            labels[i].getStyle().setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
        
        cRow21.addComponent(labels[0]);
        cRow21.addComponent(lData[1]);
        cRow22.addComponent(labels[1]);
        cRow22.addComponent(lData[2]);
        cRow2.addComponent(BorderLayout.WEST, cRow21);
        cRow2.addComponent(BorderLayout.EAST, cRow22);
        cRow1AndRow2.addComponent(lData[0]);
        cRow1AndRow2.addComponent(cRow2);

        if (displayPhoto)
            addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, cRow1AndRow2);
        else
            addComponent(cRow1AndRow2);

        focus.setUIID("bandeau_selection_list");

        this.getStyle().setBgPainter(new LigneHorizontalPainter(this, 0));
    }

public Component getListCellRendererComponent(List list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected)
    {
        Content entry = null;
        Image thumb;
        int[] tLibImpayesLength = new int[list.size()];
        int maxDataLength;
        if (value instanceof Content)
            entry = (Content)value;
        if (entry != null)
        {
            if (showPhoto)
            {
                thumb = createThumbnail(entry.getPhoto(), entry.getColumn(4));
                pic.setIcon(thumb);
            }
            lData[0].setText(Formatage.nvl(entry.getColumn(1),"-"));
            lData[1].setText(Formatage.nvl(entry.getColumn(2),"-"));
            lData[2].setText(Formatage.nvl(entry.getColumn(3),"-")); // lData[2] is the Label which displays value at the right side of the Container , the others are at the above,left and do not cause any problem

            tLibImpayesLength[index] = lData[2].getText().length();
        }
        maxDataLength = Formatage.max(tLibImpayesLength);
        if (lData[2].getText().length() < maxDataLength)
        {
            lData[2].setPreferredW(maxDataLength);
        }
        list.repaint();
        return this;
    }
```

Here is the captured image in runtime :

[image]

When we look at the image then we see that the `Impayé (Ar)` Labels and the remaining value at their right are not aligned. So how to make them vertically aligned , or have the same width ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't include the way you laid out the components in the code you posted, you also invoked setPreferredW() which effectively sabotages layout so that's obviously a mistake.

Generally to implement something like that place both of the left labels in a box layout Y and place it within the CENTER of a border layout. Place the right hand label in the EAST side of that border layout.

Comment: Are you using the Grid layout or the border layout here, the relation between your code and the image bellow is very unclear. I suggest you set a line border to the components within and see where they truly end. The spacing you see might be related to a space within the text, padding or margin of a component/parent.